# Nsubstitute can't mock interfaces with signature with in parameter

Tags: unit-testing, nsubstitute

Having this interface:

```
public interface ICandyManager
{
     IReadOnlyList<string> GetCandies(in ReadOnlySpan<byte> bytes);
}
```

When I try mock interface with nsubstitute:

```
ICandyManager nb = Substitute.For<ICandyManager>();
```

I get following error:

```
Message: System.TypeLoadException : Signature of the body and declaration in a method implementation do not match.  Type: 'Castle.Proxies.ICandyManager'.  Assembly: 'DynamicProxyGenAssembly2, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

What is a workaround for this? Obviously I can initialize real type, but I want to be able to mock it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is thrown due to a version of [Castle.Core](https://github.com/castleproject/Core) being used that [does not support reference semantics for value types](https://github.com/castleproject/Core/issues/339).

At present there are two ways I can think of to fix it:

1) Upgrade NSubstitute to [4.0.0 Release Candidate 1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NSubstitute/4.0.0-rc1) or later. This uses Castle.Core 4.3.1 (or later) and works correctly with the interface in your question.

2) Keep using NSubstitute 3.1.0, but add a reference to a more recent Castle.Core NuGet package in your test project. I tested this with NSubstitute 3.1.0 and Castle.Core 4.3.1 and my sample test started running correctly.